# Find the derivative of this integral: $h(x)=\int_5^{1/x}10\arctan(t)\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> $$h(x)=\int_5^{1/x}10\arctan(t)\,dt$$
>   
> Find $h'(x) $.

I know how to calculate the derivative of basic integrals,but this one I've been trying to solve for quite a long time,and have not yet spined my head around it. Can anyone give me some help on how I might approach such problem?

Comment: Fundamental theorem + chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)dt=f(v(x))v^\prime(x)-f(u(x))u^\prime(x).$$
Hence, letting $f(t)=10\arctan(t),$
$$\begin{align}h^\prime(x)&=f(1/x)(1/x)^\prime-f(5)(5)^\prime\\&=10\arctan(1/x)\cdot(-1/x^2)-0\\&=(-10/x^2)\arctan(1/x).\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks you very much. The general formula is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
h'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_5^{1/x}10\arctan(t)dt\right)\\
&=10\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
&=10\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$h(x)=F(x^{-1})-F(5)$ where $F'(x)=10\times arctan(x)$.

The chainrule will do the rest.